# Extract Map<String, Object> from enum with key-value attributes in one line?

Tags: kotlin

I have a general enum implementation with traditional key-value attributes:

```
enum class FooEnum(val key : String, val value : Any) {
    FOO1("FOO_KEY", "FOO_VALUE"),
    FOO2("FOO_KEY2", 0);

    companion object {
        fun getKeyValuesMap(): Map<String, Any> {
            val defaults = HashMap<String, Any>()

            for (v in values())
                defaults[v.key] = v.value

            return defaults
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better "Kotlin" way to achieve the same result of `getKeyValuesMap()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fun getKeyValuesMap() = FooEnum.values().associate { it.key to it.value }
```

Comment: I did a mixup of both answers:

val map = FooEnum.values().associate { it.key to it.value }

Comment: Yes, that's better than my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapOf(*values().map { foo -> foo.key to foo.value }.toTypedArray())
```

I'd consider using a `val` instead of `fun`, the drawback is that someone could in theory cast the result to `MutableMap` or `HashMap` and mutate it.